# select questions based on the total sum of rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

so, I'm a beginner in C# and asp.net (and in programming as whole actually :$)
, and I wanted to do simple question paper generator
, but I have some problem.

I have table 'question'

```
    [level]       INT    
    [subjectId]   VARCHAR 
    [subjectname] VARCHAR
    [question]    VARCHAR
    [answer]      VARCHAR
    [difficulty]  CHAR 
    [mark]        INT
```

with many question of different subject, level, and mark ..etc
so I wanted the user to select the level, subId, difficulty, and total mark.
in my code
it generate the question based on the selected conditions(except total mark)  and show them in gridview along side with the mark for each question and it work fine.
what I cant do is the total mark part, I want it to select only question that the sum of its mark is equal to what the user choose

I have choice for total marks

```html
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="total" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="10">10</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="15">15</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="40">40</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

so I want that when the user choose e.g 10 , it will select eg five question of 2 marks, or any questions with the sum of its marks equal to 10

I tried many ways. I used

```cs
// with group by and w/o the where condition 
" having SUM(mark) = "+total.SelectedValue+ " "
```

but I had duplicated rows(5 times) by mistake (no primary key) that the db considers as one row (a question with 2 marks)
so, that sentence selected only that row ,

and I couldn't even understand how to use 'where' and 'having' together -->//this part solved 
but it still only shows the duplicated record, and shows nothing with DISTINCT

but I want to select different rows(different question) with different marks
but I don't know how

so, is it possible to put that condition with my code, and if not, can I write the code in a different way?

```cs
con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda;
                if (dif.SelectedValue == "easy")
                {

                    sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select subjectId, level, difficulty, question, mark from addquestion where subjectId= '" + sudjectID.SelectedValue + "' and level= " + level.SelectedValue + " and difficulty = '" + dif.SelectedValue + "' ORDER BY NEWID() ", con);
                }
                else if (dif.SelectedValue == "medium")
                {

                    sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select subjectId, level, difficulty, question, mark from addquestion where subjectId= '" + sudjectID.SelectedValue + "' and level= " + level.SelectedValue + " and difficulty = '" + dif.SelectedValue + "' ORDER BY NEWID() ", con);
                }
                else if (dif.SelectedValue == "hard")
                {

                    sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select subjectId, level, difficulty, question, mark from addquestion where subjectId= '" + sudjectID.SelectedValue + "' and level= " + level.SelectedValue + " and difficulty = '" + dif.SelectedValue + "' ORDER BY NEWID() ", con);
                }
                else
                    sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select subjectId, level, difficulty, question, mark from addquestion where subjectId='" + sudjectID.SelectedValue + "' and level=" + level.SelectedValue + " ORDER BY NEWID() ", con);

        sda.SelectCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();

                con.Close();
```

I've really tried many things in many way, and I almost have read the Internet :'), and watched all the YT :') but I couldn't find any solution.
 even I was hoping to find complicated things that I wont understand it but will ask how to do it, but I didn't :')
so thank you a lot whoever will help <3

and this my generate page if it help

```html
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Subject ID"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="sudjectID" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>CSC-101</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>3-COMP-011</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>COMP3-112</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>COMP-151</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>COMP-213</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>INFS-241</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>COMP-003</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>COMP-336</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>COMP-004</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>COMP-433</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
         <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Level"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="level" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>            <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Difficulty"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="dif" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>easy</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>medium</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>hard</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>random</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Total Mark"></asp:Label>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="total" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="10">10</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="15">15</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="40">40</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Height="35px" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Generate" Width="92px" />
         <br />
         <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this part

> and I couldn't even understand how to use 'where' and 'having'
>   together

this is a simple syantax for it :

```
SELECT columns, aggratiotion functions (e.g. SUM, COUNT ..etc)
FROM tableName
WHERE 
    column = value 
GROUP BY columns 
HAVING 
 (aggratiotion functions) = value
```

example :

```
SELECT 
    subjectId
,   level
,   difficulty
,   question
,   SUM(mark) 
FROM 
    addquestion 
WHERE 
    subjectId   = somevalue
AND level       = somevalue
AND difficulty  = somevalue
GROUP BY 
    subjectId
,   level
,   difficulty
,   question
HAVING 
    SUM(mark) = somevalue
```

for the C# part, you're complicating things on yourself. give yourself a break, and forgot about it, this will help you gain more focus and also clearer thoughts whenever you work again on it.

For starter, you could simply adjust the query to this :

```
"SELECT DISTINCT subjectId, level, difficulty, question, SUM(mark) FROM addquestion WHERE subjectId = '" + sudjectID.SelectedValue + "' AND level = " + level.SelectedValue + " AND difficulty = '" + dif.SelectedValue + "' GROUP BY subjectId, level, difficulty, question HAVING SUM(mark) = " + total.SelectedValue + " ORDER BY NEWID()";
```

same principle. The additional DISTINCT would avoid duplicates.

Though, it's recommended to use a parameterized query, but I didn't want to make things worse ;). as long as you're learning, keep your focus on what are you learning and in time you'll master this part as well.

here is an example from your code (not tested, it's just for demonstration purpose).

```
string query = string.Empty;

string[] difficulties = {"easy", "medium", "hard"};

if(!difficulties.Contains(dif.SelectedValue))
{ 
    query = string.Format("SELECT DISTINCT subjectId, level, difficulty, question, SUM(mark) FROM addquestion WHERE subjectId = '{0}' AND level = {1} GROUP BY subjectId, level, question HAVING SUM(mark) = {2} ORDER BY NEWID()", sudjectID.SelectedValue, level.SelectedValue, total.SelectedValue); 
}       
else
{
    query = string.Format("SELECT DISTINCT subjectId, level, difficulty, question, SUM(mark) FROM addquestion WHERE subjectId = '{0}' AND level = {1} AND difficulty = '{2}' GROUP BY subjectId, level, difficulty, question HAVING SUM(mark) = {3} ORDER BY NEWID()", sudjectID.SelectedValue, level.SelectedValue, dif.SelectedValue, total.SelectedValue); 
}       


var dataTable = new DataTable(); 

using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
using(SqlCommand command =  new SqlCommand(query, con))
using(SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
{
    con.Open();
    adapter.Fill(dataTable);
}

GridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

anything under the select, it'll be shown to the user, if you want to hide for instance the SUM(mark), just remove it from the select.

**UPDATE**

```
    if (!difficulties.Contains(dif.SelectedValue.ToLower()))
    {

        query = string.Format("SELECT subjectId, level, difficulty, question FROM (SELECT *, SUM(mark) OVER(PARTITION BY subjectId ORDER BY subjectId ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) TotalMark FROM addquestion) d WHERE subjectId = '{0}' AND level = {1} AND TotalMark <= {2}", sudjectID.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim().ToLower(), level.SelectedValue, total.SelectedValue);
    }
    else
    {
        query = string.Format("SELECT subjectId, level, difficulty, question FROM (SELECT *, SUM(mark) OVER(PARTITION BY subjectId, difficulty ORDER BY subjectId ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) TotalMark FROM addquestion) d  WHERE subjectId = '{0}' AND level = {1} AND TotalMark <= {2} AND difficulty = '{3}'", sudjectID.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim().ToLower(), level.SelectedValue,total.SelectedValue, dif.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim().ToLower());
    }
```

Comment: First of all, thank you really for helping ,I tried this ``` "SELECT DISTINCT subjectId, level, difficulty, question, SUM(mark) FROM addquestion WHERE subjectId = '" + sudjectID.SelectedValue + "' AND level = " + level.SelectedValue + " AND difficulty = '" + dif.SelectedValue + "' GROUP BY subjectId, level, difficulty, question HAVING SUM(mark) = " + total.SelectedValue + " ORDER BY NEWID()"; ``` but it gave me " ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified." so, I removed ORDER BY NEWID() for now and tried again . but it shows nothing , no error but no result,

Comment: and when I removed DISTINCT , it shows that duplicated record only. so what could be the problem .. and for //here is an example from your code (not tested, it's just for demonstration purpose). , WOW, it made me see how much my code is stupid :D , I tried your, it's simpler and more efficient, but still have order by error, and this time with or without DISTINCT , it shows only the duplicated row. I tried it on another table w/o duplicated rows, but I got nothing for result. and thank you really for making things seems simpler

Comment: @Lojain if you can provide a sample data from the table (addquestion) it'll help me to debug it and give you an answer. However, you can always query the table directly (outside the code) and check the results, then match that results with your app results. if mismatched, then you have to work on your code to fix it.

Comment: @Lojain if you're using try/catch blocks, ensure your catch blocks is not  empty, make it return the exception errors to be able to trace it.

Comment: here a link to the table if it's easier [link] http://www.mediafire.com/folder/o6mvv7sr8ohjgz9,px5anqxn764c5k1/shared , and if not, tell me please to edit my question and put a picture . and for (you can always query the table directly (outside the code) and check the results,) do you mean using sql  database manger? because I'm  dealing with the db from vs , but if it will help, I'll download it

Comment: and I already tried try/catch but nothing , because it doesn't give error, just no result

Comment: aside from that, why my mention isn't appearing like yours :D

Comment: @Lojain you can always query the table from VS (SQL Server Object Explorer > Databases > right click on your database and choose New Query) from there you can query your table directly outside the code.

Comment: @Lojain could you tell me what is the purpose of the `Total Mark` if I choose for instance 10, does it mean it'll give me a random 10 questions ? and addquestion table, the `mark` what is it for ?

Comment: @Lojain your subjectId column (in the database) has different values than the dropdownlist in your project. So, this might be the reason that you don't see any results.

Comment: (your subjectId column (in the database) has different values than the dropdownlist in your project.) no no it's the same now, I just was trying different values to see if it will help(but it didn't), I changed it back in the question

Comment: the purpose of total mark , if you choose 10 it will give you questions that the sum of each mark is equal to 10 , e.g one question with the mark= 5 , two questions with mark=2 , one question with mark= 1 , or   it could give two questions with mark = 5 . So in the end the sum for the mark column for the result questions is equal to totalMark(which is 10 for example)

Comment: @Lojain alright, check the update, just replace it and it'll do the trick. remember to use ToLower() when reading strings, to match your conditions.

Comment: WoW it really works !! ♥ . that's really a code I wasn't going to figure it out by myself . so I'm really so grateful to you. you did a lot of efforts and work and was patient with me. , there're new things in that code that are new to me. I'm going to search about them to learn them well. and I hope that I will progress to reach a level of helping people like you

Answer (score 1):

Your questions has too many doubts, let me clarify one of them.. and then go over the rest.

> //and I couldn't even understand how to use 'where' and 'having'
>   together//

Where clause is used to filter a large data set.

Having is used to filter the Grouped data. Basically used with Group By clause.

In this example, I'm querying filtering for questions whose score is > 2 first then group the scores and display all the scores which has at least 3 questions.

SELECT Score, Count(*) as questions by score FROM Questions where score > 2 Group By Score Having count(*) >= 3

Comment: I'm guess you want to show random questions whose score equates to user selection.  If user select 10 you want to system to display 2 - 5 score question or  1 - 2 score and 2 - 4 score question  and so on...

You can try randomizing 

If user selects 10 then
SELECT TOP 5 score FROM yourtable where score = 2 or score = 4  ORDER BY NEWID()  this will return 5 rows.. you can try and filter how many adds up to 10

When user selects 15

SELECT TOP 5 score FROM yourtable where score = 3 or score = 5  ORDER BY NEWID()

These are some ideas..

Comment: thank you, and sorry that my question is confusing. my main doubt is to get (mark +=) equal to 'totalMark', I tried your method but I didn't get the part "If user selects 10 then SELECT TOP 5 score FROM yourtable where score = 2 or score = 4 " because the result will be more than 10, if u meant "If user selects 10 then SELECT TOP 5 score FROM yourtable where score = 2 "and I didn't understand it. it works but, it will only shows 5 q of score = 2, and I want something that isn't limiting, like on a click 2 q of score = 5, on another one q of score=5, two of score = 2, one of score = 1,and so on